# How can I use @WebMvcTest and also add in my own custom filters?

Tags: java, spring, testing, spring-boot

Spring Boot 1.4 added `@WebMvcTest` that wire up the parts needed to do test a web slice of my application. This is fantastic, however I also want to ensure my custom filters and security code is wired up so I can validate that is working correctly too.

How can I add in custom filters when using `@WebMvcTest`?

Answer (score 7):

`@AutoConfigureWebMvc` currently import the following auto-configuration classes (see `spring.factories` in the `spring-boot-test-autoconfigure` jar):

```
# AutoConfigureMockMvc auto-configuration imports
org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc=\
org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcSecurityAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcWebClientAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcWebDriverAutoConfiguration
```

Out of this list `MockMvcSecurityAutoConfiguration` will automatically provide integration with the security filter.

If you need to add support for additional filters you can write your own `MockMvcBuilderCustomizer` (see `MockMvcSecurityConfiguration.SecurityMockMvcBuilderCustomizer` for inspiration).

You can either use nested `@TestConfiguration` class to hook your customizer into a specific test, you you could add your own `spring.factories` and use the `AutoConfigureMockMvc` key to automatically add it to all tests.

Answer (score 3):

When using `@WebMvcTest` with Spring Security and a custom Filter, it will automatically be configured into the `MockMvc` instance. You can see this working in [rwinch/spring-boot-sample/tree/so-38746850-webmvctest-customfilters](https://github.com/rwinch/spring-boot-sample/tree/so-38746850-webmvctest-customfilters). Specifically, the [DemoApplicationTests](https://github.com/rwinch/spring-boot-sample/blob/so-38746850-webmvctest-customfilters/src/test/java/com/example/DemoApplicationTests.java) demonstrates that Spring Security is properly setup and the custom filter is setup.

Spring Boot automatically adds all the `Filter`s are setup using [SpringBootMockMvcBuilderCustomizer.addFilters](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.4.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-test-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/servlet/SpringBootMockMvcBuilderCustomizer.java#L83-L94).

[MockMvcSecurityConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.4.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-test-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/servlet/MockMvcSecurityConfiguration.java#L54) is used to setup Spring Security's testing support (i.e. Allows using `@MockUser` by adding Spring Security's `SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.testSecurityContext()` to the `MockMvc` instance.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Spring Boot options @Phil Webb pointed out, you can use plain Spting Framework features and do something like this:

```
@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext context;

@Autowired
private FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilter;

@Before
public void setup() {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .webAppContextSetup(context)
            .addFilters(springSecurityFilter)
            .apply(SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity())
            .build();
}
```