# What's the difference between @AutoConfigureWebMvc and @AutoConfigureMockMvc?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

In which case should I use each one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use @WebMvcTest and also add in my own custom filters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38746850/how-can-i-use-webmvctest-and-also-add-in-my-own-custom-filters)

Answer (score 54):

**@AutoConfigureWebMvc**

> Use this if you need to configure the web layer for testing but don't
>   need to use `MockMvc`

It enables all auto-configuration related to the web layer and **ONLY** the web layer. This is a subset of overall auto-configuration.

It includes the following auto-configuration (see [spring.factories](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-test-autoconfigure/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories))

```
# AutoConfigureWebMvc auto-configuration imports
org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureWebMvc=\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.MessageSourceAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.freemarker.FreeMarkerAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.groovy.template.GroovyTemplateAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.gson.GsonAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.hateoas.HypermediaAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jsonb.JsonbAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mustache.MustacheAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.validation.ValidationAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration
```

**@AutoConfigureMockMvc**

> Use this when you just want to configure `MockMvc`

Enables all auto-configuration related to `MockMvc` and **ONLY** `MockMvc`. Again, this is a subset of overall auto-configuration.

It includes the following auto-configuration (see [spring.factories](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-test-autoconfigure/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories))

```
# AutoConfigureMockMvc auto-configuration imports
org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc=\
org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcSecurityAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcWebClientAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcWebDriverAutoConfiguration
```

**@WebMvcTest**

Includes both the `@AutoConfigureWebMvc` and the `@AutoConfigureMockMvc`, among other functionality.

Comment: Thank you for such a clear explanation. You've saved me a lot of trouble.