# No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, ioc-container

I am unable to test my controller class by mocking UserService.save() method to return a dummy User object.

Keep getting the following exception

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:121) ~[spring-boot-test-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-test-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124) ~[spring-test-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    ... 67 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1790) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1346) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    ... 86 common frames omitted
```

I checked my service class but all seems fine there. Moreover the code runs perfectly fine when I run it as a spring boot application.

Can someone help me understand why Spring IOC is unable to register the bean when running the junit test.

```
@SpringBootTest
public class TestUserController {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    
    @MockBean
    UserService userService;
    
    @Autowired
    private UserController controller;


    @Test
    public void contextLoads() throws Exception {
        assertThat(controller).isNotNull();
    }

    @Test
    public void checkUserRegistrationEndpoint() throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        UserDto userDto = new UserDto();
        User user = new User();
        
        Mockito.when(userService.save(userDto)).thenReturn(user);......


@Service
public interface UserService {
    User save(UserDto user);
    List<User> findAll();
    User findOne(String username);
    AuthToken refreshToken(String refreshToken);
}

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService, UserService {

    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());......
```

NOTE: I have configured this application for JWT based authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You are autowiring `MockMvc`, so you need to provide the `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` annotation on your test class, which will tell Spring to inject this class for you (as stated in the [docs](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/)):

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class TestUserController {
....
}
```

The same annotation includes registration of various Spring auto-configuration classes as stated in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48728079/11812518), among others the `MockMvcSecurityAutoConfiguration`, which offers auto-configuration for Spring Security for tests (as stated in the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.13.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/servlet/MockMvcSecurityAutoConfiguration.html)).

If this does not solve your problem with the missing bean dependency, you can try to inject it with @MockBean too:

```
@MockBean
UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
```