# Spring boot unit test mvc with spring security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-test-mvc

Here is my UserController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/users")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/current")
    public User getUser(){
        return userService.getCurrentUser();
    }

}
```

Here is the test which tests the rest endpoints in the controller.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(UserController.class)
public class UserControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @MockBean
    private UserService userService;

    @Test
    public void getUser() throws Exception {
        when(userService.getCurrentUser()).thenReturn(new User("Name", "LastName"));
        mvc.perform(get("http://localhost:8080/users/current")).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.response.firstName").value("Name"))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.response.lastName").value("LastName"));
    }
}
```

this test work. After that I add springSecurity:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

And the filter is:

```
public class ApiAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
private final RequestMatcher requestMatcher;

public ApiAuthenticationFilter() {
    this.requestMatcher = new OrRequestMatcher(
      new AntPathRequestMatcher("/users/**"));
  }

  @Override
  protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {
    if (requestMatcher.matches(request)) {
      return true;
    }

    return super.shouldNotFilter(request);
  }

  @Override
  protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
  }

}
```

and I add configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Bean
  public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    ApiAuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter = new ApiAuthenticationFilter();
    http.addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class).csrf().disable();
  }

}
```

But now test not work:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status 
Expected :200
Actual   :401
```

But I set `AntPathRequestMatcher("/users/**"))`

```
http://localhost:8080/users/current
```

This works perfectly in my browser but the test is failing with an Unauthorized exception. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I think `SecurityConfig` and `ApiAuthenticationFilter` not loaded into the context while starting the test.

Try adding:

```
 @SpringBootTest(classes =  { Application.class }, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
```

Here, `Application` class is the main class where the configurations are loaded.

**Edit 1**

Other [way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38834700/967808) seems interesting.